# subview of uiscrollview not scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i'm having a scrollview, it has A (UITableView) and B(UIView) as subviews. I've also provided the scroll.content size.

It is scrolling is possible when i do scroll from A and outside B.

Problem is with B, i'm unable to provide scroll. If i provide NO to **user interaction enabled** property of B, it is scrolling. How can i able to provide scroll on B with the property **user  interaction enabled** as YES.

B view - has events to handle with..

Help me regarding this

Comment: set your scrollview contentsize of scroll.

Answer (score 0):

its depend on the content size of the scrollview. so provide the content size like .
`scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(0,A.frame.size.height+B.frame.size.height);`

**  Note: UITableView have a scroll attribute but UIView don't have scroll attribute, so UIView will scroll with UIScrollView only if added properly into UIScrollView.**

Comment: I've designed using XIB, hence no doubt that B is subclass of Scrollview. Regarding height, both A and B are having same height. In scrollview, A will be displayed in left and B in Right.

Comment: I had just created a sample as per your comment, its working fine.  Can you just increase the content size a 100 pix for test. Or you can share a code, I can look into it.